# Transferring iPhone Provisioning Profiles

Tags: iphone, certificate, provisioning

I thought there had already been a similar question but searching for it yielded no results. So if anyone can find it and link me I would appreciate it.

I have not done any iPhone development in months (*Since last August I believe*) and since then, I have reformatted my MacBook when I installed Snow Leopard. Well, I am interested in working on an iPhone application now. **My question is**, how do I go about continuing iPhone development? More specifically, I did not back-up my provisioning files and/or certificates. Do I just go back to the developer center and re-do the steps required to get the provisioning files?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Apparently it wasn't clear when I mentioned that I did not back-up my provisioning files. By this I mean I did not back-up the contents of my keychain *or* the certificates I downloaded from the developer center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure quite what you mean when you say you didn't back-up your provisioning files and/or certificates.  Did you back up your Keychain and other user data?  If so, you can restore that, then re-download the provisioning profile from the portal.

If you also lost the contents of your Keychain when you reformatted, and don't have any way of restoring them, you may have to talk to Developer Support.  At a minimum you'll have to go through the certificate request process again.

**Once you get the situation sorted out, follow the steps [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices/devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW8) to back up all your development info!**

Comment: Yeah, I did not backup the contents of the keychain (Didn't even know that was possible, aside from straight-up forgetting to).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to regenerate a certificate through the developer portal, and then generate new profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just download the certificates you already created unless they are expired in which you just need to renew them.  You can also simply restore them from a backup which I'm sure you have :)